# Solving distance-d independent set in a simple way

Tags: graphs, np-complete, clique, vertex-cover

I'm solving distance-d independent set problem, as a follow up to my [last question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124336/has-anyone-seen-a-np-graph-problem-like-this-before?noredirect=1#comment260341_124336). I'm not quite experienced in a subject, so I'm looking for a simple algorithm (which has to be an exact algorithm). So far I have:

1. Input: undirected planar grid graph $G$, which might not be "full", but be  a subgraph of a full rectangular grid. Also, a natural numbers K (size of independent set) and L (distance).
2. Represent graph as a adjacency list (or dictionary of adjacency sets, it should be more efficient), since it's sparse (property of planar grid graphs).
3. Calculate $G^L$ ([graph power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power)) with BFS - $O(V*E)$ ([complexity explanation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124391/understanding-depth-limited-bfs-time-complexity/124394#124394))
4. Solve independent set problem.

The last one has at least a few solutions:

1. Find independent set with brute force - $O(2^V * V^2)$
2. Calculate complement of $G$ in polynomial time (I think $O(V+E)$, but I'm not sure) and check if it contains a clique of size $K$, e. g. with brute force, which for fixed K is polynomial - $O(V^K * K^2)$
3. Since Independent Set and Vertex Cover problems are complementary, find Vertex Cover of size $V - K$; there exists simple algorithm with complexity $O(1.47^{VC size}$) - $O(1.47^{V - K})$

My questions (simple = understandable and "code-able" in less than 1 day for an undergraduate student):

1. Am I missing something here altogether and should I go other route, without calculating $G^L$, e. g. vertex coloring?
2. Is there a simple direct independent set algorithm better than brute force?
3. Am I right that VC is straight up better than brute force clique here?
4. [Wikipedia article on clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs) states that maximum clique can be found by simple enumeration in $O(1.4422^n)$. For my fixed size k, can this bound be tightened? If so, how should I modify the clique enumeration algorithm? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: The _kth_ power of a _degenerate_ graph of maximum degree Δ is itself <Δ^k degenerate.  Hence you can look for independent set in degenerate graphs.  I believe this problem admits a linear kernel in _d_-degenerate graphs, so you could look into FPT algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry although I prefer to think of simple answers, ur Q triggers in my mind addressing other problems (a level of a research topic not an under graduate task)

Anyways, here is what popped up in my mind just incase u find something inspiring in them

-About the Kth Largest Subset problem http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2015.09.015

-About Goemetric Set Packing problem 
(I myself didn't study it a lot, but read some papers about it when someone suggested it to me. I did not use it in my work, but the way u r trying to describe ur problem tells it has a Goemetric landscape nature so maybe it will be useful for u)

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772112000740

https://slideplayer.com/slide/4514539/

I have more resources if u need so

.

Finally, u may search for exact MWIS algorithms and u'll find a lot. Here is one paper
"Exactly Solving the Maximum Weight Independent Set Problem on Large Real-World Graphs", Sebastian Lamm
, Christian Schulz, Darren Strash, Robert Williger, Huashuo Zhangk. 
arXiv:1810.10834v1 [cs.DS] 25 Oct 2018